# Error: Unexpected type - Java

Tags: java

me pusieron el siguiente enunciado:
Codifique un programa OO que determine cuánto dinero ahorra una persona , durante un año si considera que cada semana ahorra 13% de su salario (considere cuatro semanas por mes y que el salario no cambia.).

Se solicita presentar:  el ahorro mensual y cuánto será el ahorro al año de dicha persona. Además del  dato de entrada. Defina un constructor por defecto.    Posteriormente se asignarán los valores para realizar el proceso.

Este es mi codigo pero por alguna razon que desconozco me sale el error unexpected type - Java
en las lineas que dicen: `(salario/13)*100=sSemana;`    `sSemana*4=sMensual;`  `sMensual*12=sAnual;`

```
import java.io.*;
    class AhorroPersonal {
    private float salario;
            float sSemana;
            float sMensual;
            float sAnual;
    AhorroPersonal(){  //Este constructor es llamado por new cuando se crea un objeto. 
        salario=100.00f;
     }
    
    public void Interes(){
        //Ahorro SemanaL

        (salario/13)*100=sSemana;
        //Ahorro Mensual
        sSemana*4=sMensual;
        //Ahorro Anual
        sMensual*12=sAnual;
    }
   
     public float set_sMensual( )
    {
     return sMensual;
    }
    
     public float set_sAnual( )
    {
     return sAnual;
    }
    
 }
public class Ahorro {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        // programa principal 
        
        AhorroPersonal objeto = new AhorroPersonal(); // El constructor es llamado en el objeto
               
        System.out.println(objeto.Set_sMensual());
        System.out.println(objeto.Set_sAnual());
 }
}
```

Comment: Si estás intentando asignar algo a sSemana, debe ir a la izquierda de la expresión.

Answer (score 0):

El método *Interes* se encuentra de esta manera:

```
public void Interes(){
    //Ahorro SemanaL

    (salario/13)*100=sSemana; //Esto esta mal
    //Ahorro Mensual
    sSemana*4=sMensual;
    //Ahorro Anual
    sMensual*12=sAnual;
}
```

Debería estar como te muestro a continuación:

```
public void Interes(){
    //Ahorro SemanaL

    sSemana = (salario/13)*100;
    //Ahorro Mensual
    sSemana*4=sMensual;
    //Ahorro Anual
    sMensual*12=sAnual;
}
```